# Как сделать так, чтобы этот код не работал на смартфонах?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Как сделать так, чтобы этот код не работал на смартфонах и ничего не отображалось на странице из этого кода, когда пользователь заходит с телефона на сайт?

```
<style type="text/css">

#fixed1 {
  display: table;
  height: 120%;
  width: 240px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
  left: 85%;}

.fixed1 {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: left;
}
</style>
 <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<div id="fixed1">
  <div class="fixed1">
  <button onclick="hideme(this)">ЗАКРЫТЬ?</button>

<!-- 23123132123 -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:240px;height:400px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-8511102670529458"
     data-ad-slot="4753546420"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
</div>
</div>
<script>
function hideme(obj){
    obj.parentNode.style.display = "none";
}</script>
<script>
jQuery(function(f){
    var element = f('#fixed1');
    f(window).scroll(function(){
        element['fade'+ (f(this).scrollTop() > 200 ? 'In': 'Out')](500);          
    });
    f(window).scroll(); // !!!
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.fixed1 { display: inline; }
/* Smartphone Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 480px){ .fixed1 { display: none; }}
```

Добавил в CSS

Answer (score 2):

Для этого нужно определить тип устройства, например, на PHP с помощью либы http://mobiledetect.net/ или ей подобной. Результат ее работы передать в шаблон, и на его основе добавлять или не добавлять javaScript. Для css лучше использовать @media запросы.

Либо универсальный вариант - стили и скрипты для мобильных девайсов вынести в отдельные файлы и если либа детектирует устройство как мобильное, то подключать их.

Вот пример:

```
 PHP    
 function isMobile() {

    require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
    $detect = new Mobile_Detect;

    return $detect->isMobile();
 }

 if (isMobile()) {
    //тут подключаем или вставляем скрипты и стили только для мобильных устройств
 }
```

Comment: Мне наоборот нужно ! Чтоб на мобильных не отображалось ????

Comment: ну так перепешите условие, - если if(isMobile) = true , то пусто, - else  - выводите свой код.

Comment: Нужно в условие добавить отрицание, вот так
if (!isMobile()) {

Answer (score 0):

Проверять, если используется телефон, то `die()`.

```
function mobileDetect() { //Определяет, мобильный ли браузер. Возвращает true или false.
    $headers = '';

    foreach ($_SERVER as $key => $value) {
        if (strpos($key, 'HTTP_') === 0 && $key != 'HTTP_HOST' && $key != 'HTTP_CONNECTION') {
            $key = strtolower(strtr(substr($key, 5), '_', '-'));
            $headers .= $key . ': ' . $value . "\r\n";
        }
    }

    $opts = array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => "GET",
            'header' => $headers,
            'timeout' => 6
        )
    );

    $response = file_get_contents('http://phd.yandex.net/detect', false, stream_context_create($opts));

    // Распаковать строку
    $response = gzdecode( $response );

    if (preg_match('|<yandex-mobile-info-error>|si', $response)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Братцы Ну соберите пожалуйста а то мозги на бекрень Я один с тремя ресурсами вожусь )))) Как это все выглядеть будет в сборке с тем выше кодом ?

Comment: @Helpsetup Так за вас никто сайт делать не будет. Вам подсказали, теперь вы сами трудитесь.